# AngularJS and Angular Material performance issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am working on a angularjs application with 7 angular material tabs. I have alot of drop down lists loading from the server(just once, at page load). The problem is i have alot of animation lag when i try to switch tabs or open a md-select element (according to  chrome developer tools, between 10-30 fps at best).

I think the main issue is the large ammount of `md-option` elements generated by the `ng-repeat` in `md-selects` i have all over the app. A quick `document.getElementByTagName("md-option")` in the console reveals around 1000 DOM elements generated just for that.

How can i improve the ng-repeat speed in md-selects? Is there a way to replace the ng-repeat with md-virtual-repeat in these drop down lists?

All the constant text on the page is also loaded from a language file and i've read i can use `{{ ::variableName }}` in order to prevent angular from watching that model.

Also, each tab loads its html using `ng-include="path/to/htmlFile"`. Is there a better, faster way to do that?

```
<md-tab ng-click="nextTab($event)" label="{{lang.tabPD}}" md-on-select="vm.tabName='tabPD'" md-no-pagination="true">
   <div ng-include="'app/modules/partials/tabPD.html'" ng-controller="PDCtrl"></div>
</md-tab>
<md-tab>
...another div with ng-include
</md-tab>
etc
```

Any tip you guys can give me would be deeply apreciated.

Comment: what version of angular material? Their tabs have had a lot of performance problems (see github issue tracker) that they keep trying to improve

Comment: I am using the latest release, version 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several solutions that all of them might dramatically improve you performance.

- Instead `ng-repeat` try to use [md-virtual-repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat)
- Each Tab you can put under separate `ui-view` so root tab container `state` will be `abstract:true` and tabs - the children. It should reduce DOM size a.e. only one tab is rendered
- I agree that `md-select` eats a lot of watchers so what I did: created Item component in `React**`. Works fast

---

This is `route` example of tabs from my code:

```
.state('sidemenu.activity-drill', {
                    url: '/activity-drill/:id',
                    abstract:true,
                    views: {
                        'content': {
                            templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-details.html',
                            controller: 'ActivityDetailsCtrl'
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.chat',       { url: '/chat',       templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-chat.html'})
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.notes',      { url: '/notes',      templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-action-big-notes.html'})
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.ais',        { url: '/ais',        templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-action-items.html'})
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.minutes',    { url: '/minutes',    templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-minutes.html'})
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.files',      { url: '/files',      templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-media.html'})
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.flags',      { url: '/flags',      templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-flags.html'})
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.people',     { url: '/people',     templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-people.html'})
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.objectives', { url: '/objectives', templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-objectives.html' })
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.meetings',   { url: '/meetings',   templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-meetings.html' })
                .state('sidemenu.activity-drill.angular2',   { url: '/angular2',   templateUrl: 'views/activities/activity-tab-angular2.html'})
```

Tabs structure:

```
<md-tab  ng-repeat="tab in activity_details_tab_position" ui-sref="{{tab.route}}">
                <md-tab-label >
                    <span translate="{{tab.name}}"></span>                         
                </md-tab-label>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>

        <div ui-view></div>
```

Virtual repeat example:

```
        <div>
            <p>{{(meeting.timestamp_start * 1000)| date:'EEE dd MMM'}}</p>
            <p>{{((meeting.timestamp_start * 1000) | date : 'HH:mm')}}</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div layout="row">
                <span >{{meeting.meeting_name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Hope it will help,